# How to compare a value in a map with a set of known values

Tags: go

I have some code that pulls out the URL parameters from a URL and places it into a map.  I can successfully print out the values of the map items that I want to examine.

```
values := r.URL.Query()

a := values["a"]

fmt.Println(a)
```

I notice when the values print they print with "[]" surrounding them.

I'd like to value the value of each a,b,c and check to see if it is contained in a comma-delimited string.

```
allowedA = "value1,value2,value3"
```

i.e. something similar to:

```
if(contains(allowedA,a)
```

Meaning "if the value in 'a' is contained in the variable 'allowedA' then return true.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I notice when the values print they print with "[]" surrounding them.

That's because `url.Values` is `map[string][]string`, not `map[string]string`. Use `url.Values.Get` to access the parameter directly.

> I'd like to value the value of each a,b,c and check to see if it is contained in a comma-delimited string.

I'd suggest splitting the string and using the result as map keys, so that you could use the map as a set. I.e.

```
allowedAMap := map[string]struct{}{}
allowedAStrs := strings.Split(allowedA, ",")
for _, s := range allowedAStrs {
    allowedAMap[s] = struct{}{}
}
//...
if _, ok := allowedAMap[a]; !ok {
    fmt.Println("wrong a")
    return
}
fmt.Println("correct a")
```